# Adicionar campos na página conforme a opção selecionada em um menu de opções select

Tags: jquery

Eu estou criando um formulário e quero que conforme a opção selecionada no menu um código html diferente seja mostrado na tela. Estou usando jquery pra adicionar os novos campos. Porém a cada opção selecionada os novos campos são concatenados, ou seja, a cada vez que uma opção é selecionada um novo valor é mostrado, eu queria que fosse mostrado apenas uma vez. Segue o código.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( ".form-control" ).change(function(){
    var varURL = $("option:selected", this).val();
    $(".form-group").append('O valor selecionado é: ' + varURL);
});
});
```

Comment: troca o `append` por `html`

Comment: Eu já tentei, porém o conteúdo é substituído e o menu de opções desaparece.

Comment: então cria uma div dentro desse `form-group` só pra receber o `html()`

Comment: assim ele não apaga o menu

Comment: Fiz isso e deu certo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cria uma nova div dentro do `form-group`, para receber os valores, depois usando `html()` você adiciona os valores nessa `div`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".form-control" ).change(function(){
        var varURL = $("option:selected", this).val();
        $("ID_DA_NOVA_DIV").html('O valor selecionado é: ' + varURL);
    });
});
```